# Is there a way to use hdmi input in opencv with python?

Tags: python, opencv, hdmi

What is the best way to get OpenCV to read the HDMI input in python?
for example- capture live feed from a camera connected with a video telemetry receiver, which receives video from remote camera and gives HDMI out. and get that feed into Opencv and implement a face detection algorithm.

Comment: HDMI is just a voice or video transfer interface? What is the relation with OpenCV? I think your question is unclear.

Comment: For me it looks clear enugh, my only concern is that he connect gopro source to pc source, which not gonna work

Comment: what kind of hdmi input device do you use?

Comment: We have a video telemetry receiver, which receives video from remote camera and gives hdmi out"

Comment: And where does the hdmi out goes?

Comment: It goes to my laptop

Comment: Dos your laptop have hdmi input? Please share what model it is

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I'm quite sure no that he just pluged one hdmi source to another

Comment: I'm using a HDMI to USB converter that processes video on an edge device, just plug it in and it should showup as usb web camera under /dev/video0 or /dev/video1  https://www.adafruit.com/product/4669   , to get it back out as HDMI you may need to use either gstreamer or ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the HDMI grabbers I know are registered same way as regular web cameras. Therefore it will be available with

```py
cv2.VideoCapture(...)
```

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html

Comment: my problem is related to capturing live feed from a camera(like GoPro) connected with HDMI and get that feed into Opencv and implement face detection algorithm. will that work on that?

Comment: What did you connected camera to?

Comment: We have a video telemetry receiver, which receives video from remote camera and gives HDMI out

Comment: @IshumanAgarwal OS is responsible for letting the operating system recognize devices such as GoPro as cameras. Opencv does not have to do anything other than simply read the screen of the device that the OS defines as a camera.